# Initial lock screen before the pattern screen not moving

Tags: lock-screens, miui, themes

I have a new MI 3 phone with MIUI, and I tried the theme Angry paper on this, and there seems to be a problem with the initial lock screen of this theme and it won't unlock to display the pattern, and so I am unable to unlock my android mobile. Can anybody help me with this theme or any other way to unlock the initial lock screen of MIUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold Volume UP and Back key. Have you tried this?